# How are views constructed in Josh Smith's MVVM sample?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Being new to both WPF and MVVM, I'm studying [Josh Smith's article on the MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and the accompanying sample code.

I can see that the application is started in `app.xaml.cs` by constructing a `MainWindow` object, wiring it to a `MainWindowViewModel` object and then showing the main window. So far so good.

However, I can't find any code which instantiates the `AllCustomersView` or `CustomerView` classes. Using "find all references" on the constructors of those views comes up with nothing. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WPF's DataTemplate is doing the magic. For example when you set content of a Contentcontrol with an instance of CustomerViewModel with the below DataTemplate in your resource dictionary (usually in app.xaml). Then you are gonna see CustomerView usercontrol coming up in the UI.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CustomerViewModel}">
  <vw:CustomerView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I found the mapping in `MainWindowResources.xaml` now.

Comment: Hi Jobi, I know its an old post, but I have related question, so I will be glad to get your opinion: I managed to understand that every time we set the a content property to xxxViewModel instance, an xxxView object will be rendered. But I couldnt find where does he actually SET the content property in the code...?